# mysql related: how to choose all option_name = 'template' in all multisite sites?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, phpmyadmin, command

I am trying this command to choose all wp_%_options tables in all sites:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'wp_%_options') as t
```

But I need to get one level deeper and get the option_name = 'template' in all of these folders.

Tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name like 'wp_%_options') as t WHERE option_name='template'
```

Not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to filter tables by `option_name` which is column of each `wp_%_options` table, am I right?

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov Yes. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can not treat table name (or column name) as variable in your standard SELECT queries. To solve the task you have to write a stored procedure.

The stored procedure should:

1. Fetch all table names `wp_%_options`;
2. Walk through the fetched names and select from the second level what you need using PREPARE statement.

   ```
   DELIMITER | 

   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_my_tables;

   CREATE PROCEDURE get_my_tables (IN option_name VARCHAR(255)) 
   BEGIN 

   DECLARE table_name CHAR(255);
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE first INT DEFAULT TRUE;
   DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT `tables`.`TABLE_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`tables` `tables` WHERE `tables`.`TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'wp_%_options';
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

   OPEN cur1;

   read_loop: LOOP
       FETCH cur1 INTO table_name;
       IF done THEN
           LEAVE read_loop;
       END IF;

       IF (first) THEN
           SET first = FALSE;
           DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `result_table`;
           SET @sql = CONCAT("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `result_table` (SELECT * FROM `", table_name ,"` WHERE `option_name` = '", option_name, "')");
       ELSE
           SET @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO `result_table` SELECT * FROM `", table_name, "` WHERE `option_name` = '", option_name, "'");
       END IF;

       PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
       EXECUTE stmt; 
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cur1;

   SELECT * FROM `result_table`;

   END; 
   | 
   DELIMITER ;

   CALL get_my_tables('template');
   ```

I tested this example now it works as expected. You should tune some logic for your needs. For example: how to work with temporary table, fetch fesult and maybe use `UNION` instead of temporary table.

Comment: Can I do that on PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: it is called routines maybe?

Comment: if you have required privileges to create procedures then yes.

Comment: I should do something like this right? $sql = SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'wp|__|_options' ESCAPE '|'
SELECT * FROM $sql WHERE option_name = 'template';

Comment: @Viachesiav Dobromyslov I did this and it works for giving me all the tables but can't get the right colums: create procedure test() 
  SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'wp|__|_options' ESCAPE '|';

Comment: i've just added an example. note it's not tested yet.

Comment: I've tried that and it exists now but I cannot get the list of option_name that I wanted. What I do after I have this Procedure?

Comment: just call it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/call.html I also added it to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end:

```
UPDATE  wp_2_options SET option_value='classic' WHERE option_name='template' OR option_name='stylesheet';
```

Then I created as many as I need in Excel. Took me 1 min to change them all.

Answer (score -1):

Try using LIKE instead of =.
So that the second query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name like 'wp_%_options') as t WHERE option_name LIKE 'template'
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'option_name' in 'where clause'